# xdebug connection refused to Docker container

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, xdebug

error:

```
2020/04/26 23:43:48 [error] 8#8: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.208.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://192.168.208.3:9000", host: "127.0.0.1", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/"
```

Cannot make connection with xdebug.
Docker configuration was taken from here https://gitlab.com/martinpham/symfony-5-docker/-/tree/master/docker

xdebug was installed separately and it's recognized by IDE.

Also added this in docker-compose.yml under php-fpm environment:

```
environment:
- XDEBUG_CONFIG:remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_enable=1 remote_autostart=off xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

What else needs to be added/modified ?

Comment: what else do you see in your docker logs?

Comment: Can you paste your xdebug.ini config and your PHPStorm's Xdebug debug port and the DBGp proxy settings please?

Comment: Could you please provide your xdebug settings here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I setup recently docker + php + xdebug for http-services. I guided my peers through it and it worked out flawlessly.

#### 1. Add ENV PHP_IDE_CONFIG into your docker fpm pool config

You need to add this environment into your php-fpm pool config. It could be `www.conf` (as an example)

```
env[PHP_IDE_CONFIG] = "serverName=localhost"
```

#### 2. Add xdebug.ini to your docker container

Here is an example of the xdebug.ini which I used for the setup:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = off
xdebug.remote_host = host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1500
```

#### 3. [IntelliJ IDEA or PHPStorm] - Setup PHP servers

1. Open `Preferences`
2. Go to `Languages & Frameworks` -> `PHP` -> `Servers`
3. Set **Name** to **localhost** (It's important and should match `PHP_IDE_CONFIG` value)
4. Set **Host** to **localhost**
5. Enable `use path mappings`
6. Map your project root path to the docker workdir (e.g. `/var/www/html`) so IntelliJ can correctly map the paths.

#### 4. [IntelliJ IDEA or PHPStorm] - Setup IDE key

1. Open `Preferences`
2. Go to `Languages & Frameworks` -> `PHP` -> `Debug` -> `DGBp proxy`
3. Set **IDE key** to **PHPSTORM**

#### 5. Add XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM to your url/cookie..

Finally:

- add a `?XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM` to your url OR
- add a cookie with the name `XDBEUG_SESSION` and the value `PHPSTORM`

Comment: The part #2 here is the most important since debugger need to know what to connect to when debugging begins. [This article](https://phauer.com/2017/debug-php-docker-container-idea-phpstorm/) has the schema that portrays how host, container and IDE are interconnected. The answer given by this post’ author is exhaustive.

Answer (score 2):

Issue was in:
environment:

```
- XDEBUG_CONFIG:remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_enable=1 remote_autostart=off xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

1. it's not correctly parsed.
2. if i pass only remote_host=host.docker.internal then it will pass "localhost" instead of host IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is for PHPStorm users, but if any VSCode users stumble upon here then two things that need to be done different to PHPStorm (More in this answer for PHPStorm https://stackoverflow.com/a/61561910/3056278) -

1. Pass IP address of your host (192.168...) instead of `host.docker.internal`
2. Configure pathMappings in your debug launch configuration -

```json
{
    "name": "Debug Docker",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "port": 9000,
    "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/app": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
},
```

Replace `/var/www/app` with your own path!